# Add Class to one dropdown Remove Class From others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an overlay Menu that has 3 dropdowns.

When you click on one of the parent items if it has a dropdown , a class is added to the child  to "activate" the dropdown and it expands and shows. Currently it works fine , and on click the class is added and removed if clicked again.

The problem is currently you can have all dropdowns active and open at the same time. What I need to happen is to have only one dropdown be able to be active at a time.

if one dropdown is active , and the user clicks on another , the original active dropdown closes and the newly clicked one becomes active.

Also if the dropdown is active and user clicks on the same parent item again the dropdown closes.

**Current HTML**

I have excluded all other list items except for the ones that have dropdowns.

```
<ul class="header__overlay-nav">

              <li class="js-overlay-dropdown-trigger">
                <a class="header__overlay-nav-links" href="#">
                  After Action Review
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-down btn__icon-right"></i>
                </a>

                <ul class="dropdown--overlay">

                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Overview
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Review Form
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Performance Card
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Recent Recordings
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>



              <li class="js-overlay-dropdown-trigger">
                <a class="header__overlay-nav-links" href="#">
                  Downloads
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-down btn__icon-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown--overlay">    
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      100 Day Challenge App
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Desktop Wallpapers
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Screen Savers
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Forms
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>


              <li class="js-overlay-dropdown-trigger">
                <a class="header__overlay-nav-links" href="#">
                  Inspiration
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-down  btn__icon-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown--overlay">    
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Get Your Mojo Working
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links href="#">
                      Game Changers
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Bold Actions - Big Rewards
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown__item">
                    <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                      Motivational Videos
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li> 
          </ul>
```

**Current Jquery**

Here is the original Jquery I was using to do a basic toggle of active class, Basically just using the toggleClass on the child UL of the clicked trigger.

Commented out , I previously tried removing all active classes and then instead of toggling the class on click element I was adding, but removing all classes , only to add it to the clicked one made it not possible to close a dropdown by clicking the same trigger again.

```
var $overlayDdTrigger = $('.js-overlay-dropdown-trigger');

var $overlayClasses = {

    // Active css Class for dropdowns in Main Overlay
    OverlayDdActive: 'dropdown--overlay-is-active',

    ButtonIconIsRotated: 'btn__icon-is-rotated',
  };

  $overlayDdTrigger.on('click', function() {

    if (_isMobile) {
      // Attempt to to remove all active classes on UL's prevents dropdown from 
      // being able to close if the same trigger is clicked twice

      // $('ul.dropdown--overlay-is-active').removeClass($overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive);

      $(this).children('ul').toggleClass($overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive);

      $(this).find('.btn__icon-right').toggleClass($overlayClasses.ButtonIconIsRotated);
    }
  });
```

Thank you for the help in advance, I know there are a lot of questions that relate to this problem on here, I did a lot of searching but could not find any that would help me with this specific case.

Comment: In click handler add this as first line `$('.' + $overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive).removeClass($overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive);`

Comment: @Tushar
Thanks for the reply,

Isnt that essentially the same thing as , my commented out line of code? It is just removing all the current active classes on the page. With that line it makes it impossible to close a dropdown by clicking the same trigger twice.

Comment: @VinceBrown It's hard to tell what's nested in what in your HTML and the classes are too verbose.

Comment: @zer00ne all the triggers have a class 'js-overlay-dropdown-trigger'  all dropdowns have a class 'dropdown--overlay'. The formatting of the code might not be the best with nesting because it was copy and pasted , but the classes being to "verbose" is merely a preference and has no effect on the problem at all.

Comment: @VinceBrown The problem with huge class and id names is that it makes everything unreadable and prone to human error. Organized, succinct, and semantically sound code is important especially if you were to share with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured Out a solution that works as wanted.

```
$overlayDdTrigger.on('click', function() {

    if (_isMobile) {

      // Toggle Class On clicked Element
      $(this).children('ul').toggleClass($overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive);

      // Remove all Active Dropdowns From all Siblings
      $(this).siblings().children('ul').removeClass($overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive);

      $(this).find('.btn__icon-right').toggleClass($overlayClasses.ButtonIconIsRotated);

    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work plz comment if it cause any problem.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var $overlayDdTrigger = $('.js-overlay-dropdown-trigger');

        var $overlayClasses = {
            OverlayDdActive: 'dropdown--overlay-is-active',
            ButtonIconIsRotated: 'btn__icon-is-rotated',
          };

        $overlayDdTrigger.on('click', function() {

          if($(this).find('ul').hasClass('dropdown--overlay-is-active')){

            $overlayDdTrigger.find('ul').removeClass($overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive);
            $overlayDdTrigger.find('.btn__icon-right').removeClass($overlayClasses.ButtonIconIsRotated);
          }else{

            $overlayDdTrigger.find('ul').removeClass($overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive);
            $overlayDdTrigger.find('.btn__icon-right').removeClass($overlayClasses.ButtonIconIsRotated);
            $(this).find('ul').addClass($overlayClasses.OverlayDdActive);
            $(this).find('.btn__icon-right').addClass($overlayClasses.ButtonIconIsRotated);
          }
        });
        </script>
            <style>
        .dropdown--overlay{
        display:none;
        }
        .dropdown--overlay-is-active{
        display: block !important;
        }
        </style>
        <ul class="header__overlay-nav">

        <li class="js-overlay-dropdown-trigger">
          <a class="header__overlay-nav-links" href="#">
            After Action Review
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down btn__icon-right"></i>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown--overlay">

            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Overview
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Review Form
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Performance Card
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Recent Recordings
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>



        <li class="js-overlay-dropdown-trigger">
          <a class="header__overlay-nav-links" href="#">
            Downloads
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down btn__icon-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown--overlay">    
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                100 Day Challenge App
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Desktop Wallpapers
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Screen Savers
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Forms
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="js-overlay-dropdown-trigger">
          <a class="header__overlay-nav-links" href="#">
            Inspiration
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down  btn__icon-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown--overlay">    
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Get Your Mojo Working
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links href="#">
                Game Changers
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Bold Actions - Big Rewards
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown__item">
              <a class="dropdown__links" href="#">
                Motivational Videos
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li> 
        </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is solution has the same problem as my commented out one, It does not make it possible to close a dropdown by clicking the same trigger twice.

Comment: ohh.. i understand let me check it and i will get back here.

Comment: hi.. please check the edited answer i have set js to close  dropdown by clicking the same trigger twice.

Comment: Thank you for helping , I was able to figure out an answer ( posted above ) But much appreciated you took the time to work out a solution.